# How to find flights with a large enough seat pitch to use a laptop?

Tags: air-travel, seating

I usually fly first class, so I never thought too much about using a computer in coach, but I was flying coach on American today in a 737, and I could not use my computer because the seat in front of me was so close. Some news articles says other airlines have done the same thing, so that laptop computers can no longer be used.

Is there any US-based carrier that enough room in coach to use a full size laptop computer?

I looked up the dimensions on seat guru and this is what it said:

[image]

**So, apparently I was in one of the 31" planes. How can I tell if it is a 35" pitch plane?**

Comment: This question is impossible to answer because it depends on the user, as well as the aircraft (seats are not exactly the same on all an airline's aircraft). I frequently use a full-size laptop in economy. It's not exactly as comfortable or productive as sitting at my desk but I make it work. You (or someone) pays for an upgrade because those seats have more legroom and are more comfortable.

Comment: @HarryVervet Nobody on the flight in coach was using a laptop, it wasn't just me. The biggest machines I saw in use were iPads. So don't tell me I can "make it work". Nobody was "working" on that flight.

Comment: I've used my full size ThinkPad on a United 737, but I was in the exit row...I wouldn't even try it anywhere else in economy.

Comment: The size of the laptop is certainly a factor too.

Comment: Seatguru is neither official nor is it accurate. http://seatexpert.com/seatmap/62/American_Airlines_Boeing_737-800/ will show you only the 31-32" configurations and the difference between 31 and 37 is suspicously close to https://www.aa.com/i18n/aboutUs/ourPlanes/boeing-737-800.jsp "up to 6 more inches of legroom" AA toutes for Main Cabin Extra. I would suggest paying for Main Cabin Extra if you want 35" , it won't happen otherwise.

Comment: Hmmmm, I would have expected that the obesity epidemic would have let to more room per seat, but apparently that's not the case.

Comment: What size is your laptop? I've used my 15" frequently in coach and it was okay, although there obviously wasn't enough space for an external mouse.

Comment: The solution is to buy a first class ticket ;)

Answer (score 4):

No. I know this site doesn't allow for such short answers but seriously: no. These days for a little extra legroom you are expected to pay for, Premium Economy under various names (United Economy Plus, American Airlines Main Cabin Extra, Delta Comfort+).

Edit: [Alaska too](http://splash.alaskasworld.com/Newsroom/ASNews/ASstories/AS_20151203_095607.asp).

Comment: That's really unbelievable. Just a few years ago I could use laptop computers no problem in coach.

Comment: Maybe someone didn't recline? Yes, before deregulation it was 35 inches typically and it's 31-ish now but that has been a case since, well, since you can have a laptop :) Here's a http://www1.airliners.net/aviation-forums/general_aviation/read.main/373886 thread I found from 2001 where it was 31-32 on BA.

Comment: @LemuelGulliver That's the way things are going, people want cheap flights not space. Maybe if you are desperate you can do a little work in the cramped conditions, but if your time is that important to you, you need to pay for the extra space.